# how to re rank after drop a row in data in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a data result from recommender system like this
for example

```
id          content_id       Rank
08773338    aaaa              1
08773338    bbbb              2
08773338    cccc              3
08333777    bbbb              1
08333777    aaaa              2
08333777    cccc              3
```

then I want to drop 'bbbb' content id so that it becomes like this

for example

```
id          content_id       Rank
08773338    aaaa              1
08773338    cccc              3
08333777    aaaa              2
08333777    cccc              3
```

How do I re-rank the rank column after the bbbb label is removed?

like this

```
id          content_id       Rank
08773338    aaaa              1
08773338    cccc              2
08333777    aaaa              1
08333777    cccc              2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `groupby.rank` after masking/subsetting the dataframe:

```
u = df[df['content_id'].ne("bbbb")].copy()
u['Rank'] = u.groupby("id")['Rank'].rank(method='dense')#.reset_index(drop=True)
```

---

```
print(u)
        id content_id  Rank
0  8773338       aaaa   1.0
2  8773338       cccc   2.0
4  8333777       aaaa   1.0
5  8333777       cccc   2.0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with [grp.cumcount](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.cumcount.html):

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
df = pd.read_table(StringIO("""id          content_id       Rank
08773338    aaaa              1
08773338    bbbb              2
08773338    cccc              3
08333777    bbbb              1
08333777    aaaa              2
08333777    cccc              3"""), sep="\s+")

df = df.loc[df["content_id"] != "bbbb", :]
df["Rank"] = df.groupby("id").cumcount() + 1
```

Output:

```
        id content_id  Rank
0  8773338       aaaa     1
2  8773338       cccc     2
4  8333777       aaaa     1
5  8333777       cccc     2
```